# VS code : Jupyter server connection with password instead of token

Tags: authentication, visual-studio-code, passwords, jupyter-notebook, token

The VS code `jupyter` extension allows connection to the remote `jupyter` server with token authentication.

`http://X.Y.196.198:8888/?token=abcdefgxxxx`

But my team's `jupyter` server is configured to allow access by password.
In this case, how can I connect to the server?

Comment: It's the same as with token, choose `Existing` option when [adding the server](https://retifrav.github.io/blog/2020/05/27/jupyter-notebook-nginx/images/vscode-jupyter-server.png) in VS Code and set the `http://X.Y.196.198:8888` there. When VS Code will be connecting to the server, it will warn you about "*connecting over HTTP without a token*", and then it will ask you for the password (which sadly you will need to enter every time you connect, as there doesn't seem to be a way to save it).